# Hooking mmap system to provide real-time type conversion?

Tags: c, linux, mmap

I'm working on some stuff where I want to memory map some large files containing numeric data.  The problem is that the data can be a number of formats, including real byte/short/int/long/float/double and complex byte/short/int/long/float/double.  Naturally handling all those types all the time quickly gets unwieldy, so I was thinking of implementing a memory mapping interface that can do real-time type conversion for the user.

I really like the idea of mapping a file so you get a pointer in memory back, doing whatever you need and then unmapping it.  No bufferology or anything else needed.  So a function that reads the data and does the type conversion for me would take a lot away from that.

I was thinking I could memory map the file being operated on, and then simultaneously mapping an anonymous file, and *somehow* catching page fetches/stores and doing the type conversion on demand.  I'll be working on 64-bit so this would give you a 63-bit address space in these cases, but oh well.

Does anyone know if this sort of mmap hooking would be possible, and if so, how might it be accomplished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes(-ish).  You can create inaccessible `mmap` regions.  Whenever anybody tries to touch one, handle the `SIGSEGV` raised by fixing its permissions, filling it, and resuming.

```
long *long_view =
   mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
double *double_view =
   mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_NONE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);

static void on_segv(int signum, siginfo_t *info, void *data) {
    void *addr = info->si_addr;
    if ((uintptr_t)addr - (uintptr_t)long_view < 4096) {
        mprotect(long_view, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE);
        /* translate from double_view to long_view */
        mprotect(double_view, 4096, PROT_NONE);
    } else if ((uintptr_t)addr - (uintptr_t)double_view < 4096) {
        mprotect(double_view, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE);
        /* translate from long_view to long_view */
        mprotect(double_view, 4096, PROT_NONE);
    } else {
        abort();
    }
}

struct sigaction segv_action = {
    .sa_sigaction = on_segv,
    .sa_flags = SA_RESTART | SA_SIGINFO,
};
sigaction(SIGSEGV, &segv_action, NULL);

long_view[0] = 42;
/* hopefully, this will trigger the code to fixup double_view and resume */
printf("%g\n", double_view[0]);
```

(Untested, but something along these lines ought to work...)

If you don't want to fill a whole page at once, that's still doable I think... the third argument can be cast to a `ucontext_t *`, with which you can decode the instruction being executed and fix it up as if it had performed the expected operation, while leaving the memorry `PROT_NONE` to catch further accesses... but it'll be a lot slower since you're trapping every access rather than just the first.

Comment: How expensive do you think handling those seg faults would be?  I really like this solution and I'm OK with a bit of a performance hit.

Comment: Also, would this in any way work for the write side of things?  Or just for converting on read?

Comment: @gcd This should work just as well for writes as for reads, assuming you can convert both ways.

Comment: How would it work though? On the first right to a protected page, this handler would get called, and I would presumably convert the present data, and then the program would continue on doing other stuff to the page, and I'd never see those changes.  Also, someone elsewhere pointed out that mprotect isn't safe to call from a signal handler, is there a way around that?

Comment: @gct You'd convert back from the writable page to the original (now inaccessible) page on some other event, such as touching the original page or perhaps an explicit sync or close.  It's true that `mprotect` isn't specified as async-signal-safe, but I believe it's safe in practice on Linux.

Comment: After playing for a bit I think I came across a potential show stopper.  If I don't access the memory first, and I pass it to a system call like write(), I just get an EFAULT out of it, rather than having it hit the memory and cause a translation.

Comment: @gct Ah yes, that will happen.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

The reading part sounds somewhat doable to me. I have no experience in that, but in principle having a signal handler fetch your data and translate it as soon as you access a page that is not yet present in your user-presented buffer should be possible. But it could be that such a thing would be quite inefficient, you'd have a context switch on every page.

The other way round would be much harder I guess. Per default writes are asynchronous, so it will be difficult to capture them.

So "half" of what you want could be possible: always write the data in a new file in the format that the user wants, but translate it automatically on the fly when reading such a file.

But what would be much more important for you, I think, that you have a clear semantic on your different storage representation, and that you encapsulate a read or write of a data item properly. If you have such an interface (something like "store element `E` at position `i` with type `T`") you could easily trigger the conversion with respect to the target format.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a data format that's been long established, I've got to read it on my end for compatibility reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason why you're not using accessor functions?

There are two basic cases: structured data, and plain data. Structured data has mixed data types, plain data only one format of the ones you listed. You could also have support for transparent endianness correction, if you can store a prototype value (with distinct byte components) for each used type (28 or 30 bytes total for all types you listed -- complex types are just pairs, and have the same byte order as the base components). I have used this approach to store and access atom data from molecular dynamics simulations, and is quite efficient in practice -- the fastest portable one I've tested.

I would use a structure to describe the "file" (the backing file, memory map, endianness, and data format if plain data):

```
struct file {
    int            descriptor;
    size_t         size;
    unsigned char *data;
    unsigned int   endian;   /* Relative to current architecture */
    unsigned int   format;   /* endian | format, for unstructured files */
};

#define  ENDIAN_I16_MASK  0x0001
#define  ENDIAN_I16_12    0x0000
#define  ENDIAN_I16_21    0x0001

#define  ENDIAN_I32_MASK  0x0006
#define  ENDIAN_I32_1234  0x0000
#define  ENDIAN_I32_4321  0x0002
#define  ENDIAN_I32_2143  0x0004
#define  ENDIAN_I32_3412  0x0006

#define  ENDIAN_I64_MASK  0x0018
#define  ENDIAN_I64_1234  0x0000
#define  ENDIAN_I64_4321  0x0008
#define  ENDIAN_I64_2143  0x0010
#define  ENDIAN_I64_3412  0x0018

#define  ENDIAN_F16_MASK  0x0020
#define  ENDIAN_F16_12    0x0000
#define  ENDIAN_F16_21    0x0020

#define  ENDIAN_F32_MASK  0x00C0
#define  ENDIAN_F32_1234  0x0000
#define  ENDIAN_F32_4321  0x0040
#define  ENDIAN_F32_2143  0x0080
#define  ENDIAN_F32_3412  0x00C0

#define  ENDIAN_F64_MASK  0x0300
#define  ENDIAN_F64_1234  0x0000
#define  ENDIAN_F64_4321  0x0100
#define  ENDIAN_F64_2143  0x0200
#define  ENDIAN_F64_3412  0x0300

#define  FORMAT_MASK      0xF000

#define  FORMAT_I8        0x1000
#define  FORMAT_I16       0x2000
#define  FORMAT_I32       0x3000
#define  FORMAT_I64       0x4000

#define  FORMAT_P8        0x5000   /* I8 pair ("complex I8") */
#define  FORMAT_P16       0x6000   /* I16 pair ("complex I16") */
#define  FORMAT_P32       0x7000   /* I32 pair ("complex I32") */
#define  FORMAT_P64       0x8000   /* I64 pair ("complex I64") */

#define  FORMAT_R16       0x9000   /* BINARY16 IEEE-754 floating-point */
#define  FORMAT_R32       0xA000   /* BINARY32 IEEE-754 floating-point */
#define  FORMAT_R64       0xB000   /* BINARY64 IEEE-754 floating-point */

#define  FORMAT_C16       0xC000   /* BINARY16 IEEE-754 complex */
#define  FORMAT_C32       0xD000   /* BINARY32 IEEE-754 complex */
#define  FORMAT_C64       0xE000   /* BINARY64 IEEE-754 complex */
```

The accessor functions can be implemented in various ways. In Linux, functions marked `static inline` are as fast as macros, too.

Since the `double` type does not fully cover 64-bit integer types (since it has only 52 bits in the mantissa), I'd define a number structure,

```
#include <stdint.h>

struct number {
    int64_t   ireal;
    int64_t   iimag;
    double    freal;
    double    fimag;
};
```

and have the accessor functions always fill in the four fields. Using GCC, you can also create a macro to define a struct number using automatic type detection:

```
#define  Number(x) \
    ( __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__ (x), double)          ? number_double(x) : \
      __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__ (x), _Complex double) ? number_complex_double(x) : \
      __builtin_types_compatible_p(__typeof__ (x), _Complex long)   ? number_complex_long(x) : \
                                                                      number_int64(x) )

static inline struct number number_int64(const int64_t  x)
{
    return (struct number){ .ireal = (int64_t)x,
                            .iimag = 0,
                            .freal = (double)x,
                            .fimag = 0.0 };
}

static inline struct number number_double(const double  x)
{
    return (struct number){ .ireal = (int64_t)x,
                            .iimag = 0,
                            .freal = x,
                            .fimag = 0.0 };
}

static inline struct number number_complex_long(const _Complex long  x)
{
    return (struct number){ .ireal = (int64_t)(__real__ (x)),
                            .iimag = (int64_t)(__imag__ (x)),
                            .freal = (double)(__real__ (x)),
                            .fimag = (double)(__imag__ (x)) };
}


static inline struct number number_complex_double(const _Complex double  x)
{
    return (struct number){ .ireal = (int64_t)(__real__ (x)),
                            .iimag = (int64_t)(__imag__ (x)),
                            .freal = __real__ (x),
                            .fimag = __imag__ (x) };
}
```

This means that `Number(value)` constructs a correct `struct number` as long as `value` is an integer or floating-point real or complex type.

Note how the integer and floating-point components are set to the same values, as far as type conversions allow. (For very large integers in magnitude, the floating-point value will be an approximation. You could also use `(int64_t)round(...)` to round instead of truncate the floating-point parameter, when setting the integer component(s).

You'll need four accessor functions: Two for structured data, and two for unstructured data. For unstructured (plain) data:

```
static inline struct number file_get_number(const struct file *const  file,
                                            const size_t              offset)
{
    ...
}

static inline void file_set_number(const struct file *const  file,
                                   const size_t              offset,
                                   const struct number       number)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that `offset` above is not the byte offset, but the index of the number. For a structured file, you'll need to use the byte offset, and add a parameter specifying the number format used in the file:

```
static inline struct number file_get(const struct file *const  file,
                                     const size_t              byteoffset,
                                     const unsigned int        format)
{
    ...
}

static inline void file_set(const struct file *const  file,
                            const size_t              byteoffset,
                            const unsigned int        format,
                            const struct number       number)
{
    ...
}
```

The conversions needed in the function bodies I omitted (...) are quite straightforward. There are a few tricks you can do for optimization, too. For example, I like to adjust the endianness constants so that the low bit is always a byte swap (ab -> ba, abcd -> badc, abcdefgh -> badcfehg), and the high bit is a short swap (abcd -> cdab, abcdefgh ->cdabghef). You might need a third bit for 64-bit values (abcdefgh -> efghabcd), if you want to be completely certain.

The if or case statements within the function body do cause a small access overhead, but it should be small enough to ignore in practice. All ways to avoid it will lead to much more complex code. (For maximum throughput, you'd need to open-code all access variants, and use `__builtin_types_compatible_p()` in a function or macro to determine the correct one to use. If you consider the endianness conversion, that means quite a few functions. I believe the very small access overhead -- a few clocks at most per access -- is much more preferable. (All my tests have been I/O bound anyway, even at 200 Mb/s, so to me the overhead is completely irrelevant.)

In general, for automatic endianness conversion using prototype values you simply test each possible conversion for the type. As long as each byte component of the prototype values are unique, then only one conversion will produce the correct expected value. On some architectures integers and floating-point values have different endianness; this is why the `ENDIAN_` constants are for each type and size separately.

Assuming you have implemented all of the above, in your application code the data access would look something like

```
struct file    f;

/* Set first number to zero. */
file_set_number(&f, 0, Number(0));

/* Set second number according to variable v,
 * which can be just about any numeric type. */
file_set_number(&f, 1, Number(v));
```

I hope you find this useful.

Comment: Wow thanks for the very in depth reply.  This would probably work for me with some changes, since I have a lot of types to support, but I'd basically have to change it to support reading buffers of data since I almost never interact with just one entry at a time.  I like the idea of just interacting with the data through a pointer, because typically the file just represents a large contiguous chunk of stuff, so it fits really well with the pointer paradigm.  I'm a big fan of the static inline paradigm for header libraries though.